# c++ Fast Way to Store txt values into vector<int>

Tags: c++

I want to store my text values into my int vector, using c++.

My text values are:
250
251
251
252
......

If my text values are char (e.g.)
afv
atd
agg
.....

Then I would use

```
vector<std::string> arr;
std::string path = "C:\\myText.txt";
glob(path,arr,false);
```

But for integer values inside text file, above code is not possible to implement.

Therefore I implemented following code:

```
vector<int> arr;
ifstream stream("C:\\myText.txt");
int num;
while(getline(stream,line)){
    istringstream(line) >> num;
    arr.push_back(num);
}
```

My question is: is there any faster way for implementing above code?

Something like using glob method for integer implementation?

Comment: I didn't know `getline()` works with integers

Comment: @FirstStep: `istringstream >>` does the conversion.

Comment: @user so `getline()` takes the whole `line` as a string and put it in `stream` then what does `istringstream` do exactly? what is the value of `num` on the first iteration? thanks **Edit:** Only if every line has only one integer, then it will make sense and the OP's text values were misleading me

Comment: _@Ahmed_ Not necessarily faster, but shorter ways to write are available using a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) IIRC.

Comment: @FirstStep Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream

Comment: @Firststep : It creates a new `std::istringstream` initialised with the contents of `line` after which you can use the istringstream in the same way as any other stream and use it's `>>` operator. Just like `std::cin >> a_int;`

Comment: I wonder if `cv::glob` is 'faster'. It's probably implemented in a similar way. Have you benchmarked both examples? Taking into account the extra string->int conversion needed.

Comment: reading the entire file into a buffer and then parsing it will be faster. The actual parsing is a drop in the bucket compared to the file io.

Comment: @user1320881 You're right, but first I should learn how to benchmark functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be faster but it is fewer lines of code and does no rely on constructing a `istringstream` from a `std::strign` for every line.  Since a vector can be constructed from a iterator range we can use a [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) constructed from the `ifstream` object and a default constructed one to mark the end of the file

```
std::ifstream fin("test.txt");
std::vector<int> data{ std::istream_iterator<int>(fin), std::istream_iterator<int>() };
```

This will read the integers from the file and insert them directly into the vector.  I am not sure if this would be fewer memory allocations then using `push_back`.

Comment: Definitely a better approach, I don't have to use variable num. and initialize istringstream inside a loop.

Comment: @AhmetTavli If you get a chance to profile the provided code I would be interested to know if it actually is faster or not.

Comment: "Profiling a Provided Code" does that mean, you want to see the whole code?

Comment: @AhmetTavli No I don't need to see it.  I was just wondering if you had tried it to see if it was faster or not.

Comment: You can find my testing code via [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/seshuzt6d1ynedp/SpeedTestingOfVectors.rar?dl=0). Result is They both nearly same, I accept your answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

> My text values are: 250 251 251 252 ......
>
> If my text values are char (e.g.) afv atd agg .....

You can omit the `getline()` and `istringstream` in both cases:

```
template<typename T> 
void glob(std::istream& is,std::vector<T>& arr) {
    T val;
    while(is >> val) {
        arr.push_back(num);
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
ifstream stream("C:\\myText.txt"); // myText.txt contains all numbers like 250 251 251 ...
std::vector<int> v;
glob(stream,v);
```

or

```
ifstream stream("C:\\myText.txt"); // myText.txt contains all words like afv atd agg ...
std::vector<std::string> v;
glob(stream,v);
```

Comment: I couldn't use stream object inside glob method, it gave me an error:  
"could not convert 'stream2' from 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' to 'cv::String {aka std::basic_string<char>}'
     glob(stream,v);"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it means, it can't convert ifstream to the string

Comment: @AhmetTavli You've probably mistaken my answer. You should pass a `std::istream&` to the template function, not the filename. Create the `std::ifstream` instance outside of the function call.